# Eclipse MapReduce plugin Error: Server IPC version 7 cannot cannot communicate with client version 3

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-plugins

When I try to connect to MapReduce location which is cluster with one namenode and datanode from my laptop (where I have my eclipse and mapreduce plugin) I get the Error: Server IPC version 7 cannot cannot communicate with client version 3. I tried to find some information on google but could not find much. Is it because my mapreduce eclipse plugin using older version IPC and the hadoop cluster has newer one. So its just that I'm using outdated plugin? How do I find which IPC version my eclipse plugin is using? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this sounds like version incompatibility. Assuming your hadoop distro has the source, you can recompile the eclipse plugin for that version.

See the:

- `$HADOOP_HOME/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin` folder
- http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn - final section on how to build the plugin

Comment: Thanks. I followed the steps mentioned above and I managed to compile the source successfully. Then I changed build.properties file to reflect the eclipse home. Then I go to above mentioned eclipse-plugin folder and did "ant jar". It says plugin build successfully. But I find only MANIFEST.MF file in it. I desperately trying to build it since two days. But no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this for full instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166125/build-a-hadoop-ecplise-library-from-cdh4-jar-files