# Build a Hadoop Ecplise Library from CDH4 jar files

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to build a Hadoop library of all the jar files that I need to a build map/reduce job in Eclipse.

What are the .jar files that I need AND from what folders of the single node install of CDH4 when installed Hadoop on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've downloaded the CDH4 tarball distro from https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/CDH4+Downloadable+Tarballs

1. Unpack the tarball
2. locate the `build.properties` file in the unpacked directory:

   `hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0/src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin`
3. Add a property to this file for your eclipse installation directory:

   `eclipse.home=/opt/eclipse/jee-indigo-SR2`
4. Finally run `ant` from the `hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0/src/hadoop-mapreduce-project` directory to build the jar

You'll now have a jar in the `hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0/src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/build/contrib/eclipse-plugin/` folder

To finally answer your question, the dependency jars are now in:

- `hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0/src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/build/contrib/eclipse-plugin/`

And to be really verbose if you want the list, see this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QFcKaFhQ)

Comment: When I did the step 4 build was successful but eclipse-plugin was not built. So I went to folder mentioned in the step 2 and ran the command ant jar. It built a plugin with version number missing(i.e. had ${version} instead of 2.0.0). When I put this plugin in the eclipse plugin the MapReduce perspective showed up properly but when I click to create New Hadoop Location nothing was happening and no error was reported. The dependency jars you talked about, should I have them at a specific location for the plugin to work properly? By the way plugin size is 2.3MB. Thanks foryourtime.

Comment: @M Dotnet: Were you able to build the plugin successfully?

Comment: @Chris White: You have a comment?

Comment: I'll have to check with the build that i last ran, i'll admit i never actually tested the plugin in Eclipse